# How to trace from which component a button was clicked

Tags: c#

I have made a gui in C# that has multiple components. each component has one button. I want to know which component the button that was clicked was from. I don't know the number of components to start off with because i allow the user to add more if they want, so I can't name them or anything to figure it out. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are hooked onto the button's Click event for each of your "Components".

In this case, make use of the "sender" parameter in the event handler and resolve it from there based on your (hopefully) known control tree structure.

```
void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var ownerControl = button.Parent as MyControl; // But you may need to walk up more levels if need be... Depends on your UI structure.

    // Do stuff with button and owner control
}
```

Or better yet, "bubble" the event from your "component" so that it will have it's own event:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;

protected virtual void OnButtonClicked()
{
    var handler = ButtonClicked;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnButtonClicked(); // Bubble the event
}
```

Then your main control (with all the "components") will hook onto ButtonClicked events for each generated item and can directly find the item from the handler's `sender` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to create an event eg. ButtonClicked on each component and then use the component as the `object sender` argument in the event handler.